# UIView and subviews - opacity

Tags: iphone, uiview, opacity

Is it possible to make a UIView (and any other subviews within it) set to an opacity of say 0.5 or whatever? Not sure if this is even possible, but want to ask.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

```
view.alpha = 0.5; // Doesn't it work?
```

Comment: I think you mean view.alpha = 0.5; That should do it, along with all its subviews.

Comment: View opacity and alpha both are different, if we change view alpha, all the subviews in tat view will be effected, if you change opacity only the particular view will be effected.